# Yahtzee multiplayer loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Have created a basic starting mechanic for a yahtzee console based game, to show 5 dice being rolled and then the various scores that are applicable. Yet, I am not able to identify how to loop the whole process 3 times like in the real game, I will post the code if needed, but it is very long so don't want to block the whole question up, just to ask for a basic 3 turned loop.

Any help  will be appreciated.

Comment: Just put the main game in: `for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){ //put code here }`

Comment: to loop 3 times, you can use: `for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)`

Comment: You don't need a loop, you need a counter.

Comment: So you can implement yahtzee logic but have problem doing a loop ?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
{
   RollDice(); //Put your code here
}
```

The for loop will assign a starting value for a variable ("int i=0") , perform some sort of function on it ("i++" -> Increment by 1) until the condition in the middle is false ("Until i is smaller than 3")

You can read the official documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx)

[Easier to understand document with examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/for)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a loop. You don't play Yahtzee by rolling three times in quick succession. Stuff happens between rolls. Just use a counter, an integer like `numberOfRollsThisTurn`, and increment it every time the user decides to roll.